# MS Lists Calculated Date Column Using Business Days

Tags: list, microsoft-lists, mslists

I'm trying to create calculated date columns in MS Lists that populates an end date by subtracting a # of business days from a start date. The start date can fall on any day of the work week (Mon -Fri). While researching how to do this, I have found ways to calculate the business days between a given start and end date, and the WEEKDAY function but not a way to use business days in the calculation.

Looking to find a way to solve for end date in MS Lists: [Start Date (Mon - Fri)] - [# of Business Days] = [End Date]